# Azure API not properly communicating with Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-api-management, http-status-code-500

Consider following resources:

- Angular Web application (localhost and also as app service)
- .Net Web API deployed to Azure as App Service and also **API Management Service**
- **Azure SQL Database**

There is an endpoint in my API that communicates with the Azure SQL Database to retrieve data.
Problem is, when calling the endpoint from inside my web-application, I get an `HTTP Error 500 Internal Server Error` back.

So far I've tried calling different endpoints of the API and they work just fine.
Only the one endpoint that has a connection to the sql database does have a problem.

In the API Management Service Portal I've enabled `trace for an hour` for this endpoint and then hit test endpoint, this is the result:

```
api-inspector (5.762 ms)
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "confidential",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "sec-ch-ua",
                "value": "\"Not.A/Brand\";v=\"8\",\"Chromium\";v=\"114\",\"Google Chrome\";v=\"114\""
            },
            {
                "name": "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
                "value": "?0"
            },
            {
                "name": "ocp-apim-subscription-key",
                "value": "c068472fa5fc4855a214589fca573f3f"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-For",
                "value": "213.232.64.36"
            },
            {
                "name": "sec-ch-ua-platform",
                "value": "\"Windows\""
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
                "value": "cross-site"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
                "value": "cors"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
                "value": "empty"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "no-cache, no-store"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept",
                "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                "value": "gzip,deflate,br"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Language",
                "value": "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
            },
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "apim-gws-vm-hub.azure-api.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "Referer",
                "value": "https://apimanagement.hosting.portal.azure.net/"
            }
        ]
    }
}
api-inspector (0.418 ms)
{
    "configuration": {
        "api": {
            "from": "/",
            "to": {
                "scheme": "https",
                "host": "confidential",
                "port": 443,
                "path": "/",
                "queryString": "",
                "query": {},
                "isDefaultPort": true
            },
            "version": null,
            "revision": "1"
        },
        "operation": {
            "method": "GET",
            "uriTemplate": "/api/CustomerSetting"
        },
        "user": "-",
        "product": "-"
    }
}
cors (0.040 ms)
"Origin header was missing or empty and the request was classified as not cross-domain. CORS policy was not applied."
cors (0.002 ms)
"Origin header was missing or empty and the request was classified as not cross-domain. CORS policy was not applied."
Backend
(171.162 ms)↑ Back to top
forward-request (0.697 ms)
{
    "message": "Request is being forwarded to the backend service. Timeout set to 300 seconds",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "confidential",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "confidential"
            },
            {
                "name": "sec-ch-ua",
                "value": "\"Not.A/Brand\";v=\"8\",\"Chromium\";v=\"114\",\"Google Chrome\";v=\"114\""
            },
            {
                "name": "Request-Id",
                "value": "|84688588-445cacf71e07bd43.84688589_"
            },
            {
                "name": "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
                "value": "?0"
            },
            {
                "name": "ocp-apim-subscription-key",
                "value": "c068472fa5fc4855a214589fca573f3f"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-For",
                "value": "213.232.64.36,20.121.82.216"
            },
            {
                "name": "sec-ch-ua-platform",
                "value": "\"Windows\""
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
                "value": "cross-site"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
                "value": "cors"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
                "value": "empty"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "no-cache, no-store"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept",
                "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                "value": "gzip,deflate,br"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Language",
                "value": "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
            },
            {
                "name": "Referer",
                "value": "https://apimanagement.hosting.portal.azure.net/"
            },
            {
                "name": "Request-Context",
                "value": "appId=cid-v1:122a11f8-2e9e-493c-9359-bc3e4fb49c3c"
            }
        ]
    }
}
forward-request (170.466 ms)
{
    "response": {
        "status": {
            "code": 500,
            "reason": "Internal Server Error"
        },
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Content-Length",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "name": "Date",
                "value": "Tue, 04 Jul 2023 08:54:08 GMT"
            },
            {
                "name": "Set-Cookie",
                "value": "ARRAffinity=6d3572b2b5d6d73206c9c4a99a5ad142df9de7ce275826b9ad09831ef137d7de;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=confidential,ARRAffinitySameSite=6d3572b2b5d6d73206c9c4a99a5ad142df9de7ce275826b9ad09831ef137d7de;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=confidential"
            },
            {
                "name": "Server",
                "value": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Powered-By",
                "value": "ASP.NET"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Also in my `appsettings.json` inside the .Net Code I have this, which should work, because another .Net API that uses the same sql connection structure but different sql server and database and it works:
`"SQLConnection": "Server=tcp:sql-myServer.database.windows.net,1433;Database=sqldb-myDB"`

And this is a snippet of the Program.cs file:

```
var connectionString = MyConfig.GetValue<string>("Azure:SQLConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CustomerSettingContext>(a => a.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Also I have added the API as app service in the IAM section of the sql server and inside the server I've added the app service as a user in the security section of the database.

Would really appreciate if someone has an idea.

Comment: Is it true, that API Management is directly connected to the App and the App is connected to SQL?. So, the App is returning error 500. What can you find in the App logs?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly" connected? The managed identity is activated for both the api as app service and the sql server. On the app service identity tab I've added the role assignment for the sql server.
The app logs are only showing that there were failures with error code 500 but nothing else.
In my description above it says "Origin header was missing or empty and the request was classified as not cross-domain. CORS policy was not applied."

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved my problem by looking into `application event logs` which are under the `diagnose problems` section in the Azure app service of the API.
There I found this error log:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'CustomerSetting', database 'sqldb-myDB', schema 'dbo'.
```

So apparently the user in my azure database, which is the app service api, didn't have the right permissions to execute commands.

So I went to give permissions by executing this command in the azure sql server management studio:

```
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [app-myApp];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [app-myApp];
```

Hope this helps someone who's having the same problem